# NSString StringWithFormat returns nil?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I created a table view with links that the user has saved. The user can click on any cell with a link and go to the direct webpage (view controller with web view). However, the link returns as null in the `prepareForSegue` method and the web view appears empty. The `stringWithFormat` may need to be rewritten. This block of code is assigned when the user clicks on a link in a table view.

TableView.m

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showArticle"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

        NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@", _toDoItems[indexPath.row]];
        [[segue destinationViewController] setUrl:urlString];
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your array of items has items? You should put a breakpoint and print out the value of your todoitem at the indexpath. If its not null it will create the string with the format that you are coding.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure _toDoItems[indexPath.row] returns a valid string for you. There are too many unknowns here. To get better help, drill down to the issue better.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, check what the other users said about your object from the array. A suggestion though, if you're performing the segue from the tableView's `didSelectRowFromIndexPath`, you can just do this:

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    id object = array[indexPath.row];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"YourIdentifier" sender:object];
}
```

Then grab your data from the sender, that way you don't have to derive it from the tableView.